# syslog-ng processing all messages after restart

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

i'm running syslog-ng inside docker, i'm collecting logs from local files, process them and then write to another logfile or send them to slack.

I noticed that whenever i need to updated syslog-ng config and restart container, syslog-ng re-reads all messages from source logfiles which causes duplications in destination files, slack channel.

Is there option to tell syslog that after reboot only new messages should be processed or maybe process only 1hour old logfiles?

i tried to google/check documentation but without luck, i'm probably not asking the question correctly because i would assume this option exist or not?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syslog-ng, by default, persists positions for sources where the concept of "bookmarking" or "position-tracking" is applicable.

This is true for regular file sources as well.
All you have to do is keep the syslog-ng persist file intact (`syslog-ng.persist` under the `/var` folder).

Comment: hi, sorry for late response. it looks like it worked. i put `/var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist` on persistent volume and after recreating container, logs are not duplicated anymore, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be losing the persist file that was mentioned by MrAnno. You could try putting this and the log file on a persisted folder so that syslog-ng can reference where it was last and process from there.

Comment: thanks, i planned to test it for some days but got busy with something else, now it seems it works ok